# Leer Parte del XML y algunos hijos con repeticiones LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente XML

```
<Detalle>
                    <Item>
                        <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
                        <CodItem>
                            <TpoCod>2</TpoCod>
                            <Cod>45136</Cod>
                        </CodItem>
                        <IndFact>3</IndFact>
                        <IndAgenteResp />
                        <NomItem>PEKITAS TOALLAS HUMEDAS 70</NomItem>
                        <DscItem>CONT:437148|DTO-FIN:4%|</DscItem>
                        <Cantidad>10</Cantidad>
                        <UniMed>UNI</UniMed>
                        <PrecioUnitario>58.00</PrecioUnitario>
                        <DescuentoPct>0</DescuentoPct>
                        <DescuentoMonto>23.20</DescuentoMonto>
                        <SubDescuento>
                            <DescTipo>2</DescTipo>
                            <DescVal>4.00</DescVal>
                        </SubDescuento>
                        <RecargoPct>0</RecargoPct>
                        <RecargoMnt>0</RecargoMnt>
                        <MontoItem>556.80</MontoItem>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <NroLinDet>2</NroLinDet>
                        <CodItem>
                            <TpoCod>3</TpoCod>
                            <Cod>45678</Cod>
                            <TpoCod>2</TpoCod>
                            <Cod>45136</Cod>
                        </CodItem>
                        <IndFact>6</IndFact>
                        <IndAgenteResp />
                        <NomItem>PEKITAS TOALLAS HUMEDAS 70</NomItem>
                        <DscItem>CONT:508195|DTO-COM:100%|DTO-FIN:4%|REF/OFE:60 u|</DscItem>
                        <Cantidad>10</Cantidad>
                        <UniMed>UNI</UniMed>
                        <PrecioUnitario>58.00</PrecioUnitario>
                        <DescuentoPct>0</DescuentoPct>
                        <DescuentoMonto>580.00</DescuentoMonto>
                        <SubDescuento>
                            <DescTipo>2</DescTipo>
                            <DescVal>4.00</DescVal>
                        </SubDescuento>
                        <SubDescuento>
                            <DescTipo>2</DescTipo>
                            <DescVal>100.00</DescVal>
                        </SubDescuento>
                        <RecargoPct>0</RecargoPct>
                        <RecargoMnt>0</RecargoMnt>
                        <MontoItem>0.00</MontoItem>
                    </Item>
                </Detalle>
```

Necesito sacar algunos elementos y el  que se encuentra dentro de Coditem del cual pueden haber hasta 5 apariciones. No estoy pudiendo sacar ese elemento. Debajo el código que estoy haciendo con linq pero no se como sacar en el mismo objeto las apariciones de cod. Me podrán ayuda? mil gracias

```
var elemento = from el in eDetalle.Descendants("Item")
                       select new 
                       {
                           NroLinDet = el.Element("NroLinDet").Value,
                           NomItem = el.Element("NomItem").Value,
                           DscItem = el.Element("DscItem").Value,
                           PrecioUnitario = el.Element("PrecioUnitario").Value,
                           Cantidad = el.Element("Cantidad").Value,
                           DescuentoMonto= el.Element("DescuentoMonto").Value,
                           DescuentoPct = el.Element("DescuentoPct").Value,
                           DescVal = el.Element("DescVal").Value,
                           MontoItem = el.Element("MontoItem").Value,
                           ACA TENDRIA QUE SACAR EL VALOR DE TODAS LAS APARICIONES DE Cod DENTRO DE CodItem
                       };
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: pero ese xml no es valido en el CodItem, si vas a tener repeticiones deberia ser  <CodItems>
 <CodItem>
  <TpoCod>3</TpoCod>
  <Cod>45678</Cod>
 </CodItem>
 <CodItem>
  <TpoCod>2</TpoCod>
  <Cod>45136</Cod>
 </CodItem>
</CodItems> necesitas reflejar una coleccion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El xml no es valido en el nodo CodItem, si vas a tener repeticiones deberia ser

```
<CodItems>
    <CodItem>
        <TpoCod>3</TpoCod>
        <Cod>45678</Cod>
    </CodItem>
    <CodItem>
        <TpoCod>2</TpoCod>
        <Cod>45136</Cod>
    </CodItem>
</CodItems>
```

necesitas reflejar una coleccion

Entonces en el linq usarias

```
CodItems = el.Descendants("CodItem").Select(x= >new {
                                      Tipo = x.TpoCod,
                                      Cod = x.Cod
                                     }),
```

sobre la seleccion aplicas una nueva para crear cada item que representa el item de codigo

Comment: Haciendo de esta manera obtengo un ienumerable con los códigos, MIL GRACIAS !!!!!   CodItems = el.Descendants("CodItem").Select(x=> new {Tipo = x.Element("Cod").Value}),